# Highcharts multi-color line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was looking to create some highchart with multi-colored line. 
If it goes down under some value, it become red, and when it comes over this value, it become green .

Here is the picture example:
[image: Gradient example]

Or maybe highcharts have some other charts models to differentiate high or low level with color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the coloring using `linearGradient` coloring:

```
color: {
    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
    stops: [
        [0, 'red'],
        [0.25, 'yellow'],
        [0.50, 'green'],
        [0.75, 'yellow'],
        [1, 'red']
    ]
}
```

Here `0` in `stops` relates to the minimum value of the series and `1` the maximum value, and everything in between are percentages between those values.

If you find the percentages according to your values prior to creating the chart you could use the correct `stops` values to make it relate to specific values in your data (at least approximately).

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0tvn1x4a/).

Comment: And could we use not percentage, just values? For example for values <10 - one color, for value >30 other color?